# Conditionally showing 'Edit' button in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I have a question about what would be the best practice for creating a conditional statement for a GridView in ASP.NET.  I have a badge number that is being passed into a new page containing a GridView and depending on that badge number, I want to have it check whether or not the user has permissions (from another db table) and display the "Edit" button if they have permission.

I guess I'm not sure about how to accomplish this.  I have tried searching and the best I can come up with is to do it during a databound event.

Any insight on this topic would be great!  Thanks!

Here is the code I have right now (the auto generated edit button for gridviews):

```
 <Columns>
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
etc
etc
etc
 </Columns>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the row databound function of the gridview you could make a call to the other db and work out whether to show the button or not. You can find the control in the gridview and then set it to be invisible.

Comment: Oh true, never thought of the 'Visible' flag.  I will see if I can get something going using that.